# Looping back to start

Tags: c#

I am building this program for my CIT class and want to have it loopback and create a new number when the number is guessed correctly.  I read over the section in my textbook that covers this but I am a little confused as to how to add this and where exactly.

Here is the code I have now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guess_My_Number
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int number;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Generate the number.
            Random generator = new Random();
            number = generator.Next(0, 100);
            MessageBox.Show("Can you guess the number I am thinking of     
            between 1 and 100?");
        }

        private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the guess from the textbox.
            int guess = Convert.ToInt32(guessTextbox.Text);

            // Check if the number is right.
            if (guess > number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too high, try again.");
            }
            if (guess < number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too low, try again.");
            }
            if (guess == number)
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you guessed my number!");
            }
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clost the program.
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a little side note, the lower bound of `Random.Next()` is **inclusive** and the upper bound is **exclusive**. If you want to have your random number between 1 and 100, then you'll have to change your code to `generator.Next(1, 101)`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5):

```
namespace Guess_My_Number
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int number;
        Random generator = new Random();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateNewNumber();
        }

        private void GenerateNewNumber()
        {
            number = generator.Next(0, 100);
            MessageBox.Show("Can you guess the number I am thinking of     
            between 1 and 100?");
        }

        private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the guess from the textbox.
            int guess = Convert.ToInt32(guessTextbox.Text);

            // Check if the number is right.
            if (guess > number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too high, try again.");
            }
            if (guess < number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Too low, try again.");
            }
            if (guess == number)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, you guessed my number!");
                GenerateNewNumber();
            }
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also modify the last MessageBox so that it asks the user if the want to start again. Use this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a reference to handle dialog input.

Comment: If you use a dialog instead, it helps the user know a new number was generated.

Comment: Instead of using Convert.ToInt32() use [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).